# Multiple Match Values Excel Function

Tags: excel, vba

i am developing this Excel VBA function to print different VLookup values According to an id i set up at (M3:M4176), so that duplicate values show different vlookup results. I made the following function to find and print these.

```
Sub Main()
Range("H5").Select
Cells(1, 1).Select 'Seleciona o Valor da célula atual
ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select 'Altera a posição da Célula 2 Células para a esquerda
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select 'Altera a posição da Célula 2 Células para baixo
Dim var As Integer
Dim result As Variant
For var = 1 To Range("H5").Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    result = Application.VLookup(Range("A5") & Range("M3:M4176").Row, Range("M3:Q41765"), False)
    ActiveCell.Value = result
Next var
End Sub
```

In pure excel, the vlookup i made to generate and test the different results work, but when applied to VBA, the result is printed, but as #Value.
Is it simply impossible to do something like this? i feel close to results, but am lost as i am learning VBA only now, by building this.
Here is the excel function that works, in cells

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(P3&ROW(M3:M4176);M3:Q4176;5;FALSE);"")
```

Comment: Can you [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75137993/edit) to include the formula that works? (also, please check to make sure the code I edited is still correct)

Comment: Your lookup is searching column M for a value in Column A, then outputting value in column Q?

Comment: Is there a misprint in this `Range("M3:M4176").Row, Range("M3:Q41765")` ?

Comment: like this? `=VLOOKUP(A4,$M$4:$Q$28,5,FALSE)`

Comment: What do you mean by _duplicate values show different vlookup results_ ?

Answer (score -1):

Well I'm still not sure about a lot of things you want from your code, but here is a basic example of how to use VLookup with VBA, iterating through a range.

```
Sub MyLookup()
    
    Dim RG As Range     'The whole range we're placing values into
    Dim CL As Range     'Individual cells in RG
    Dim I As Long       'Iteration
    Dim lRow As Long    'Last Row
    
    lRow = Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row    'Lookup last row in M column
    Set RG = Range("C4:C" & lRow)                   'Set Range
    
    For Each CL In RG.Cells     'Iterate through Range
        'the Value of each cell (CL) in this range (RG) = WSfunction: VLookup ( _
            look for ( value -> offset from Col C to col A), _
            look in ( M column to Q column, fro row 4 to lastrow), _
            Return ( 5th column), _
            False)
        CL.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup( _
            CL.Offset(0, -2).Value, _
            Range("M4:Q" & lRow), _
            5, _
            False)
    Next CL
    
End Sub
```

And this is the output:

[image]